# Как работает этот код?

Tags: java, строки

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "hello";
        int mas[] = new int[3];

        test(mas);
        test2(s1);

        System.out.println(mas[0]);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

    static void test(int massive[]) {
        massive[0] = 1;
    }

    static void test2(String string) {
        string.concat("111");
    }
}
```

В обоих случаях для ссылочных типов передается копия ссылки на объект. Но только в случае с массивом мы меняем этот объект. А в случае со строкой на место переменной нового объекта не создается(я помню что саму строку изменить нельзя).

Почему? Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: `String.concat` ничего не меняет, он возвращает новую строку

Answer (score 4):

Метод `String.concat()` конкатенирует текущую строку с аргументом и **возвращает** полученную строку. Исходная строка **не модифицируется**.

Схематично выглядит это так

```
class String {
  public String concat(String arg) {
    return this + arg;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Regent Вы правы. Доуточнил

Answer (score 3):

Сама ссылка на строку передается по значению, то есть создается копия ссылки аргумента. Функция работает с копией ссылки.

```
string.concat("111");
```

Однако исходная ссылка не меняется. Более того этот метод не меняет исходную строку. Он создает новую строку. Так что в любом случае исходная строка не меняется даже если вы в функции напишите

```
string = string.concat("111");
```

Вы можете представить определение метода и его вызов следующим образом

```
test2(s1);

// ...

static void test2( /* String string */) {
    String string = s1;
    string = string.concat("111");
}
```

В случае с массивом, то меняется память, занимаемая объектом, на который ссылается ссылка при использовании оператора индексации.

Comment: Т.е. без добавления "return'а" объект стринга в ссылке исходного метода никак не изменить?

Comment: @chakki изменить можно, но на практике такого делать определённо не стоит. Да и даже думать об этом не стоит.

Answer (score 2):

> `String.concat` ничего не меняет, он возвращает новую строку

В других ответах эта тема раскрыта, я же хотел добавить следующее.
Строки в Java немутабельны. Это, помимо прочего, гарантирует вам, что объявленная, как `String a = "string";` строка не может быть изменена никем, кому бы вы её не передавали.
Другие классы/методы могут создавать новые строки на основе этой, но не в состоянии изменить вашу.
Пока вы самостоятельно не замените значение `a` новым значением(`a = getNewStr();`) вы можете быть уверены в его неизменности.
Даже заменяя значение таким образом, вы не меняете исходную строку, а лишь меняете ссылку на вновь созданную. Если где-то сохранились указатели на старое значение(`String b = a;`), они в безопасности.

---

*Этим свойством(`immutable`) обладают все классы-обёртки примитивов(`Integer`, `Long` и тп).*

Comment: Вообще говоря, это ведь не совсем так. Ситуация, при которой код `String string = "abc"; changeString(string); System.out.println(string);` приведёт к выводу на экран, например, `0bc`, вполне реальна. Другое уж дело, что это серии "не пытайтесь повторить это дома".

Comment: Способы те же, что и для `поменять значение константы`? Их лучше не знать.

Comment: Да, всё те же. Да, наверно, не стоит учить людей плохому.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "hello";
        int mas[] = new int[3];

        test(mas);
        s1 = test2(s1);

        System.out.println(mas[0]);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

    static void test(int massive[]) {
        massive[0] = 1;
    }

    static String test2(String string) {
         return string.concat("111");
    }
```

Вот вариант рабочего кода. Просто что бы изменить обьект(поле обьекта) нужно оброщатся к нему по ссылке.